# RabbitMQ - How do you programatically receive messages from the message queue?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

Here is what I have so far. I've been able to successfully publish a message to a queue and see that it is there via RabbitMQ's management console.

However, when I try to receive it, it does not seem to trigger the callback function at all.

Here is the relevant code.

```
MessageQueue mq = new MessageQueue();

mq.Receive("task_queue", (model, ea) => {
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ea.Body);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
});
```

Here is my `Receive` function in the `MessageQueue` class:

```
    public void Receive(string queueName, EventHandler<BasicDeliverEventArgs> onReceived)
    {
        using (IConnection connection = GetConnection(myLocalhost))
        {
            using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: queueName, durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                // Don't dispatch a new message to a consumer until it has processed and acknowledged the previous one.
                channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel); // non-blocking

                // Set the event to be executed when receiving a message
                consumer.Received += onReceived;

                // Register a consumer to listen to a specific queue. 
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName, autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I try to run the `Receive` function while there is something in the queue, nothing is printed to my output window.

Can anyone help me on this?

**UPDATE**

I took the code in the `Receive` function and placed it in the same file as the code that calls it. Still no luck. That rules out a scoping issue I think. I also tried setting the `Received` field to an actual event delegate (instead of a `onReceive` function and had that call another function in which I put a breakpoint. That function is never hit leading me to believe that my event delegate callback is never being called at all.

I'm at a loss as to why this is.  The message is still being consumed from the queue as the RabbitMQ management console shows me. I've also tried renaming the queue to something else to make sure no other phantom services are consuming from the same queue. No cigar.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried extracting the two `using` statements and calling my `Receive` function inside there in order to keep the scope but that didn't work either. I even extracted the code in the whole `Receive` block out to a main function and now it doesn't even consume from the queue.

Comment: Most likely, your program is consuming the message, but exiting before the callback is called. I would give further suggestions but as you haven't provided the complete source code to your program I would just be guessing.

Comment: Does the server show the message being consumed? Does it show the consumer connected?

Comment: Yes, the message is consumed but there doesn't seem to be any consumers listed in the `Consumers` section of the queue in the management console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code above, you have a pretty straightforward problem.

The instant after you call `channel.BasicConsume`, the whole thing (connection/channel) goes out of scope and is immediately disposed/destroyed via the `using` statement.

To prevent this from happening, you need to have an infinite loop immediately following the `channel.BasicConsume`, with appropriate logic of course to exit when you shut down the program.

```
while (_isRunning & channel.IsOpen) {
    Thread.Sleep(1);
    // Other application logic here; e.g. periodically break out of the
    // loop to prevent unacknowledged messages from accumulating in the system
    // (if you don't, random effects will guarantee that they eventually build up)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand the issue but adding an infinite loop doesn't seem to work for me. In my class where I call the `Receive` function, I need to do other work afterwards. I can't just have it hang on `Receive`. Is there a way to have this be non-blocking?

Comment: I'm starting to think that the way the code is organized is a bit incorrect. The sending of a message can simply be a function call but the receiving of messages needs to be run in a main program as a separate process.

Comment: That is one option, or you can use `EventingBasicConsumer`

Comment: Wait, I am using `EventingBasicConsumer`. Why is it that I can't get it to work by calling the `Receive` function then?

Comment: You'll still have to dispatch from a dedicated thread. There is no way around this. However, I created a more robust, observable implementation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49619839/catching-events-prior-to-subscription-with-fromeventpattern).